# Why Does the Currency of In-app Product Prices in My App Automatically Change when I Change the Currency for Another App in AppGallery Connect?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery

I used my Huawei developer account to sign in to AppGallery Connect, in which I have two game apps – app A, which was released in Singapore and app B, which was released in Thailand. On the product management page, the default currency of in-app product prices in app A is USD. However, when I selected THB as the currency for in-app product prices for app B, the currency for app A also changed to THB. I want to know what is the currency determined by?

Comment: Please read [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/14945696).and also read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

The "Default Currency" in Product Management page is meant for you to set the base currency on all of your IAP products. You can then apply different base price values according to this currency for each individual app.

[image]

Once the default currency is set, IAP will use this currency and the value to auto-adjust other country's currency and values for each IAP product. If you change the default currency, it will be applied to all of you app IAP products, so what you are seeing is correct.

If you would like to make sure that your user see custom currency and pricing based on their country, you can adjust it individually by country. For more information, please refer to this document - https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/agc-create_product#h2-1603115682022

Answer (score 0):

1.The currency of an app is not determined by the default language, but is instead determined by your default currency setting, as shown in the configuration item below.

[image]

2.Currently, if you change the default currency of in-app product prices for any one of your apps, the default currency for all of your apps will also be changed to that currency.

This is a known issue and changes will be implemented in the near future.